# Is it possible to create a text file in PHP?

Tags: php, file, member

I‘m planning to create a website with a members database. And i want to perform an action that support this concept. The concept is: when anybody signed up to my website, i want PHP automatically to create a profile url for that user. Is that possible?

Comment: Everything is possible.

Comment: @JohnConde ... and more.

Comment: The infinite is unknown at Zombo.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is possible. Although, it would be much better for you to keep records in a database, and use a file like profile.php which would load data depending on an ID, instead of creating a file for each of your users.

EDIT: More details.
The program flow looks like this:

1. There is a page where someone can **register**. That page will save the posted data using the database.
2. The data in the database will look like so:
   `ID | Name | Email`

   `1  | John | john@johnsite.com` etc. You get the point.
3. There will be a profile.php file which will get an ID, probably from the URL. That is done using `$_GET`.
   Some code for that may look like so:
   `$id = mysql_escape_string($_GET['id']);`
   `$resource = mysql_query('SELECT FROM the_table WHERE ID = "'.$id.'"')`
   `$profile = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);`
   `print "<h1>".$profile['Name']."'s Page!</h1>";`

That would result in a URL like profile.php?id=1
and a page showing
**John's Page!**


Caution: You need to consider many things when writing an ID in the URL. You may want to encrypt it into md5 first, and select also using the sql function md5.
You should definitely avoid printing anything for Ids like -1, 0 and you should try not to use the ID for anything like opening file paths, etc.

Comment: Could you explain more please. I‘m interested in this idea.

Comment: Sure. I will edit the answer to add more details, so that I can format it better.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible. You could create a file of and write to it with the following:

```
$profileFile = "profileFile.txt";
$fh = fopen($profileFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$strToWrite = "Bob Dole\n";
fwrite($fh, $strToWrite);
fclose($fh);
```

You can read more at [tizag](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php) or [fopen on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. You will probably want to read through [PHP's filesystem functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php). You should however consider using a database for a task like this though.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to create a file with php with the function fopen, but, if you want to use database in you're website i suggest using some kind of SQL database instead (personally I recommend MySQL), it's faster, more reliable, and easly managable.